# Get/Set global variable in Class in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, global-variables

I can't understand how to  make global variable, that I can in future change its value and get it over and over again?
My controller Example:

```
public function getProducts()
{
    // some stuff
    $products = SQLquery;
    config(['memoProducts' => $products]);
    $value = config('memoProducts');
    dd($value)//returns what I need

}

public function setProducts()
{
    //here I try to get $products from previous function
    $value = config('memoProducts');
    dd($value)//returns null
}
```

What's my problem?

PS: thanks for thinking that I'm stupid af and minusing my question all day long, even though none of your answers  seem to help. Thanks a lot

Comment: use config or .env

Comment: @hafiz .env shouldn't be used for global variables, it's specifically for the environment variables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many ways to set and get global variables, one of them would be setting to `config`

```
config(['app.timezone' => 'America/Chicago']);
```

and reading that value from `config`

```
$value = config('app.timezone', 'fallback value');
```

[Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/configuration)

**EDIT**

> Configuration values that are set at run-time are only set for the current request, and will not be carried over to subsequent requests.

so you could use other techniques like [`Cache`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/cache)

```
public function setProducts()
{
    $products = SQLquery;
    Cache::put('products', $products, 60); // Third parameter is the time limit
}

public function getProducts()
{
    //here I try to get $products from previous function
    $products = Cache::get('products');
}
```

or use [`Session`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/session)

```
public function setProducts()
{
    $products = SQLquery;
    session(['products' => $products]);
}

public function getProducts()
{
    //here I try to get $products from previous function
    $products = session('products');
}
```

Comment: yeah, but how to  change its value?

Comment: Just change the value of the configuration key `config(['app.timezone' => 'new value']);`

Comment: I tried this and it worked inside of one funciton. But when I try to set value in one function, and then get in in another function of the same class I get `null`

Comment: Make sure you are using the same key to set values

Comment: `getProducts()` should be called before `setProducts()` inorder for the config key to be set. You could try `setProducts() { $this->getProducts(); // rest of the code`

Comment: well `getProducts` is indeed called before `setProducts`, so I'm a little bit confused

Answer (score 0):

You can create constants.php file inside config folder.

```
return [

    'country_name' => env('COUNTRY_NAME','Bangladesh'),
    'city_name' => env('CITY_NAME','Dhaka')
];
```

you can access this variable in two-way

```
Config::get('constants.country_name')
config('constants.country_name')
```

for blade

```
{{ config('constants.country_name') }}
```

Comment: it's not that much global to make that. I just need a few vars inside of the same class to pass data between funcitons

Comment: you can follow  in getter and setter  way  example: class Foo
{
    private $bar;
     
    public function getBar()
    {
        return $this->bar;
    }
     
    public function setBar($bar)
    {
        $this->bar = $bar;
    }
}
 
$foo = new Foo();
$foo->setBar(1);
$foo->setBar($foo->getBar() + 1);

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways to pass information through the app. First we can use `config()` to set and get.

Optionally you can use `session()` to get and set.

You could also add variables to the `request()` object such as `request()->global_var = 'test'`

Comment: I tried `request()` stuff but it didn't work between 2 funcitons

Comment: saying it didn't work doesn't help in the slightest, were there errors? Where exactly are you using the code, you haven't pasted any code or anything in relation to the question.

Comment: @linktoahref Speaking of which, I missed off the IoC and singletons as I feel it's a little more complex than what newbie would understand.

Comment: @Ian : Yes, absolutely!